# Heroku: failed connection between Redis and App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, redis

Heroku 20
Ruby: 3.1.0
Rails: 6.1.0
Redis: [Screen from gemfile.lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwsjB.png)
Redis on heroku:  6.2.3

Most likely after changing the version of redis on heroku: from free to premium, the worker stopped working. (Web is working)

```
heroku run rails c
```

```
redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])
# => #<Redis client v5.0.6 for rediss://ec2-5x.xx.xx.xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:12499/0>

redis.ping
# /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-client-0.12.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:62:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=5x.xx.xx.xx:12499 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain) (Redis::CannotConnectError)                                                    
# /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-client-0.12.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:62:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=5x.xx.xx.xx:12499 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain) (RedisClient::CannotConnectError)                                              
# /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-client-0.12.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:62:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=5x.xx.xx.xx:12499 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

```
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"], ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })

$redis.ping
# /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-client-0.12.1/lib/redis_client/connection_mixin.rb:48:in `call_pipelined': WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled. (Redis::CannotConnectError)
# /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-client-0.12.1/lib/redis_client/connection_mixin.rb:48:in `call_pipelined': WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled. (RedisClient::AuthenticationError)
```

Then I attempted to change `rediss://` to `redis://` in the URL:

```
redis = Redis.new(url: url_with_one_s, ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })
redis.ping
# /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-client-0.12.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:130:in `rescue in read': Connection reset by peer (Redis::CannotConnectError)                                                                                                                    
# /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-client-0.12.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:130:in `rescue in read': Connection reset by peer (RedisClient::CannotConnectError)                                                                                                              
# /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-client-0.12.1/lib/redis_client/ruby_connection.rb:130:in `rescue in read': Connection reset by peer (RedisClient::ConnectionError)                                                                                                                 
# /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:452:in `__read_nonblock': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
```

`Procfile`:

```
release: bundle exec rails db:migrate
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

When I run in bash:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

I get:

```
pid=4 tid=1i50 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 6.5.5 with Sidekiq::RedisConnection::RedisAdapter options {:url=>"rediss://:REDACTED@ec2-5x.xx.xx.xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:12499/1"}
W, [2023-02-14T12:22:11.722698 #4] 
pid=4 tid=1i50 INFO: Booted Rails 6.1.7.1 application in staging environment
pid=4 tid=1i50 INFO: Running in ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [x86_64-linux]
pid=4 tid=1i50 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
pid=4 tid=1i50 INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: https://sidekiq.org
pid=4 tid=1i50 WARN: Redis::CannotConnectError: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled.
pid=4 tid=1i50 WARN: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-client-0.12.1/lib/redis_client/connection_mixin.rb:48:in `call_pipelined'
```

5. 

```
heroku redis:info
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.60.2 to 7.67.1.
=== redis-xxxxx-xxxxx (REDIS_URL)
Plan:                   Premium 0
Status:                 available
Created:                2021-xx-xx xx:xx 
Version:                6.2.3
Timeout:                300
Maxmemory:              noeviction
Maintenance:            scheduled for 2023-xx-xx xx:xx:00 +0000, required by 2023-xx-xx xx:xx:xx +0000
Maintenance window:     Wednesdays xx:xx to Thursdays xx:xx UTC
Persistence:            AOF
HA Status:              Available
Requires TLS:           Yes
Keyspace Notifications: Disabled
```

Comment: The error messages are explicitly clear: you're either 1) supplying the wrong username and password (so check the [config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)), 2) supplying no username and password (so check the [config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)), or 3) you're connecting to the wrong Redis instance (so check the [config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)).